# How to eficiently find the closest point from a distinct set of points to each point of another set in python

Tags: python, distance

I have this code

```py
import random as rand


W = 2
H = 2
n_riders = 10
n_drivers = 20
riders_coords = []
drivers_coords = []
for n in range(n_riders):
    x = rand.uniform(-1,1)*W
    y = rand.uniform(-1,1)*H
    riders_coords.append((x, y))
for n in range(n_drivers):
    x = rand.uniform(-1,1)*W
    y = rand.uniform(-1,1)*H
    drivers_coords.append((x, y))
print(riders_coords)
print(drivers_coords)
```

I would like to find a way to pair each rider to the closest driver (euclidian distance) taking into account that a single driver can only be assigned to a single rider. The objective is to find the parings that minimizes the total distance. All riders should be assigned to a driver if n_riders <= n_drivers.
Does anyone know a simple way to achieve that or do I have to start drawing voronoi polygons from scratch?

Comment: I don't think there's a library that will do this more efficiently than you could by just comparing each point against others.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is known as the *Euclidean assignment problem*, or alternatively the *Euclidean bipartite matching problem*. The problem has been studied academically, and there are some known algorithms, but I didn't find any information about them except in academic papers:

- [Vaidya (1989)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1137/0218080) described an algorithm which runs in `O(n^2.5 log n)` time.
- [Agarwal, Efrat & Sharir (1999)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0097539795295936) described one which runs in `O(n^(2 + ε))` time for arbitrarily small `ε`.
- [Agarwal & Varadarajan (2004)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/997817.997856) described a heuristic algorithm which runs in `O(n^(1 + ε))` time and finds a matching with expected weight within a constant factor of the true minimum.

You can probably find a few more published algorithms or heuristics by searching the literature.